# Using Masonry in AngularJS / Bootstrap app

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I have been trying (unsuccessfully) for the past two days to use Masonry in an app. My app uses AngularJS and Bootstrap. I need to display images in Bootstrap panels. The images will be dynamically loaded. Each panel will be 200px in size. I want the panels to get added left-to-right with a maximum of four columns. There is a demo on the official [angular-masonry](http://passy.github.io/angular-masonry/) site that is similar to what I'm trying to do. They do not use panels though.

When my app runs, my panels always load vertically. There are no columns. Just one single column basically. I can't figure out why. I've created a [JSFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/go0snchx/10/). The setup for the masonry stuff is pretty simple. It looks like this:

```
<masonry>
  <div class="masonry-brick panel panel-default" ng-repeat="item in items">
    <div class="panel-heading">
      <h3 class="panel-title">{{item.title}}</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body">
      <img ng-src="{{ item.imageUrl }}" alt="A masonry brick">
    </div>
  </div>
</masonry>
```

Can someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong? I worked all weekend on this. Thank you!

Comment: in your JSFiddle angular-masonry is not even loaded, neither is masonry wich is a hard dependency for angular-masonry. Do you have an example where all the dependencies are solved?

Comment: Sorry. I added the module to the Fiddle. The problem still exists.

Comment: the dependencies are still not resolved yet. angular-masonry also has a dependency on masonry itself. Try to check if your problems occur because of missing dependencies.

Comment: I've updated the dependencies again. I've included masonry and imagesloded. It is still not working. How do you know which dependencies are missing? I see a number of .js files referenced in the source (view-source:http://passy.github.io/angular-masonry/). Yet, I don't know which are 'required' and which are for other purproses. I'm just trying to get a plain jane example going.  Thanks!